# Near Horizon Vector Field

Tags: black-holes, ads-cft, kerr-newman-metric

I am studying this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4393.pdf. I find a probem to find the near horizon form of the vector (2.17) and electromagnetic (2.18) field. I have tried to use the near horizon coordinate transformation (2.12) to the vector (2.4) and electromagnetic (2.5) field but what I got do not match the paper. Can someone give me the hint?

Comment: What did you get and how did you get there?

Comment: For simplicity, I will show for the case zero cosmological constant and magnetic charge.What I got for the vector field is $$ \frac{q(2a^2 +q^2)(a^2 sin^2\theta - 1)}{a^2(1+cos^2\theta)+q^2} r dt + \frac{aq \sqrt{a^2+q^2}sin^2\theta}{a^2(1+cos^2\theta)+q^2}d\phi .$$ I got this by using the near horizon coordinate transformation (2.12) to the vector (2.4) but first I add gauge term that is $$ \frac{\Phi}{\epsilon}r_0 d\hat{t}$$ where $$ \Phi = -\xi^\mu A_\mu |_{r=r_+}$$ and $$ \xi^\mu \partial_\mu = \partial_t + \Omega_H \partial_\phi .$$ $ \Omega_H $ is shown in Eq. (2.6).

Comment: But from the paper we see that the vector field is $$ \frac{q(a^2 sin^2\theta +q^2)}{a^2(1+cos^2\theta)+q^2} r dt + \frac{q (2a^2+q^2)(a^2 sin^2\theta +q^2 )}{2a\sqrt{a^2+q^2}(a^2(1+cos^2\theta)+q^2)}d\phi $$ for  zero cosmological constant and magnetic charge.